# Simple mapping in fluent nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have a class Client which has a attribute of dogs

```
public class ClientsMap : ClassMap<Clients>
{
    public ClientsMap()
    {           
        Id(x => x.ClientID);
        HasMany(x => x.Dogs);
    }
}

public class Client
{

    public virtual IList<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
    public virtual int ClientID { get; set; }
}
```

and a class of dog that references client.

```
public class Dog
{
    public virtual Clients Client { get; private set; }
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

public class DogMap : ClassMap<Dog>
{
    public DogMap()
    {
        Table("Pooches");
        Id(x => x.Id);

        References(x => x.Client).Column("ClientId");
    }

}
```

Because I am mapping on to an existing DB i cannot change the field names.

When I try and return the dogs collection I am getting an invalid column error on client_id with the SQL

```
SELECT 
dogs0_.Clients_id as Clients3_1_, 
dogs0_.Id as Id1_, 
dogs0_.Id as Id1_0_, 
dogs0_.ClientId as ClientId1_0_ 
FROM 
pooches dogs0_
```

How can I make this use clientid over cliet_id. I thought I specified this in the dogs map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also specify the column name on the one to many relationship.

```
HasMany(x => x.Dogs)
    .KeyColumn("ClientId");
```

Comment: i know its would be something simple... Couldn't find the answer in TFM.. thanks